# Need to autofill content type field based on other field of form

Tags: nodes

Story:
I have three content types.
Category
Project
Tasks
I have "Project Manager" field on Project content type, which is an entity referrer field.
On Task content type i have three fields 
Category
Project
Project Manager

Requirement:
i need to auto fill Category and Project Manager field when i select Project.

Comment: Followed the same.did few changes like. i add js file in .info file and the js files is in my theme directory.code for js is as follows.
(function($) {
  Drupal.behaviors.bartikCopyFieldValue = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {

      // Repeat this for all fields as needed
      $('#edit-field-sub-project-und', context).on('change', function(){ 
                   alert("hello");
        // above you can use change instead of blur if element is not changed by another js
      });
      // end of "repeat this"

    }
  };
})(jQuery);
Bartik is my theme name.

Comment: It would be better to attach the js to the form, as in the linked answer, because you only need it when the form is loaded. If you add it in the .info file it gets loaded on every page.

Comment: function bartik_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    $path = drupal_get_path('thtme', 'bartik');  
    $form['#attached']['js'][] = $path . '/js/copy_field_value.js';
}


Thats how  i m attaching now, but js file is not loading when i open the form.

Comment: There's a typo: `... drupal_get_path('thtme', ...`

Comment: :) i checked by correcting it..but still the same..

Comment: where are you adding this? did you clear caches? are you aggregating js?

Comment: i m adding it in template.php

Comment: I created a custom module.there are two files right now. ModuleName.info and ModuleName.module.php, What to do next ?

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/developing/modules/7